# Calculating Second Moment of Area of NACA Aerofoils

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to code a Python program to calculate $I_x$, $I_y$ and $I_{xy}$ for a four digit NACA Aerofoil whose outline can be calculated as follows:

The camberline is given by:

$y_c(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{M}{P^2}(2Px-x^2),  & 0\le x< P \\
\frac {M}{(1-P)^2}(1-2P+2Px-x^2), & P\le x\le 1
\end{cases}$

The gradient is given by:

$\frac{dy_c}{dx}(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2M}{P^2}(P-x),  & 0\le x< P \\
\frac {2M}{(1-P)^2}(P-x), & P\le x\le 1
\end{cases}$

A thickness distribution is generated by:

$y_t(x)=\frac{T}{0.2}(a_0\sqrt x+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4)$

where $a_n$ is a constant.

The equation of the upper surface of the aerofoil is given by:

$x_u=x_c-y_t\sin(\theta), y_u=y_c+y_t\cos(\theta)$

and for the lower surface:

$x_l=x_c+y_t\sin(\theta), y_l=y_c-y_t\cos(\theta)$

Where $\theta=\frac{dy_c}{dx}(x)$. See [here](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/naca4digit?MNaca4DigitForm%5Bcamber%5D=2&MNaca4DigitForm%5Bposition%5D=40&MNaca4DigitForm%5Bthick%5D=12&MNaca4DigitForm%5BnumPoints%5D=81&MNaca4DigitForm%5BcosSpace%5D=0&MNaca4DigitForm%5BcosSpace%5D=1&MNaca4DigitForm%5BcloseTe%5D=0&yt0=Plot) for more detail on how this works.

For calculating $I_y$ I found an MIT PDF [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-01-unified-engineering-i-ii-iii-iv-fall-2005-spring-2006/systems-labs-06/spl10b.pdf) but I don't understand how this would translate for calculating $I_y$ and $I_{xy}$. For reference the method they have used is:

$Area (A) = \int_{0}^{c}[y_u-y_l]dx$

$\overline {y} = \frac{1}{A}\int_{0}^{c}\frac{1}{2}[{y_u}^2-{y_l}^2]dx$

$I_y = \int_{0}^{c}\frac{1}{3}[({y_u-\overline {y}})^3-({y_l-\overline {y}})^3]dx$

My best guess for calculating $I_x$ is:

$\overline {x} = \frac{1}{A}\int_{y_{min}}^{y_{max}}\frac{1}{2}[{x_u}^2-{x_l}^2]dx$

$I_x = \int_{0}^{c}\frac{1}{3}[({x_u-\overline {x}})^3-({x_l-\overline {x}})^3]dx$

For $I_{xy}$ I have no idea. As a final question using this method are the second moments of area relative to the centroid of the aerofoil?

Comment: The $I_y$ they calculate is about the centroid. That is why had to calculate $\bar y$ first, and it appears in the $I_y$ integral. Your formulas for $\bar x$ and $I_x$ would be correct if you made the variable of integration $dy$ instead of $dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a constant density, the definitions of the moments of inertia *about the origin of the coordinate system* are $$I_x = \int y^2\ dA\\I_y = \int x^2\ dA\\I_{xy} = \int xy\ dA$$
Where the last one follows the more common sign convention (the inertia tensor has $-I_{xy}$ as its off-diagonal components).

In the first version of this post, I went through the derivation of the formulas in the MIT paper. But that paper is uses a different method of expressing its curves than here. The curves here are actually parametric, and that works better with a different set of formulas. First, let me recast the curves:

Note that the curves are given by $\alpha(x) = (x_l(x), y_l(x))$ on bottom, and $\beta(x) = (x_u(x), y_u(x))$ on top. Now the "$x$" upon which they vary is the x-coordinate along the camberline, not these, which makes this notation confusing. For that reason, I am changing the variable to $t$, since it is not the $x$ value for the curves we are interested in. For our purposes it is just a parameter. And similarly, to highlight the "$y$" of interest in this calculation, let me just rename $y_c$ as $u$, and $y_t$ as $v$. So:

$$ 0 \le t \le 1\\ \ \\u(t) =\begin{cases}
\frac M{P^2}(2Pt-t^2),  & 0\le t< P \\
\frac M{(1-P)^2}(1-2P+2Pt-t^2), & P\le t\le 1
\end{cases}\\
\dot u(t) = \frac{du}{dt}(t)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2M}{P^2}(P-t),  & 0\le t< P \\
\frac {2M}{(1-P)^2}(P-t), & P\le t\le 1
\end{cases}\\
v(t)=\frac{T}{0.2}(a_0\sqrt t+a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3+a_4t^4)$$

It will be helpful also to calculate $$w(t) = \frac 1{1+\dot u^2}$$
because then $\cos \theta = w(t)$ and $\sin \theta = \dot u(t)w(t)$, and so the parametric curves forming the boundaries of the airfoil are

$$\alpha(t) = (t + v(t)\dot u(t)w(t), u(t) - v(t)w(t))$$
below and
$$\beta(t) = (t - v(t)\dot u(t)w(t), u(t) + v(t)w(t))$$
above.
The full curve in the counterclockwise direction can be defined by $$\gamma : [0,2] \to \Bbb R^2$$ with
$$\gamma(t) = \begin{cases} \alpha(t) & 0 \le t \le 1\\\beta(2 - t) & 1\le t \le 2\end{cases}$$

With this parametric boundary we can use [Green's theorem to simplify the various integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensTheorem.html) (see formulas 10 through 16), Letting $(x(t), y(t)) = \gamma(t)$,

$$A = \int_0^2 x\dot y\ dt\\
\bar x = -\frac 1{2A}\int_0^2 y^2\dot x\ dt\\
\bar y = \frac 1{2A}\int_0^2 x^2\dot y\ dt\\
I_x = -\frac 13\int_0^2 (y-\bar y)^3\dot x\ dt\\
I_y = \frac 13\int_0^2 (x-\bar x)^3\dot y\ dt\\
I_{xy}= -\frac 12 \int_0^2 (y-\bar y)^2(x-\bar x)\dot x\ dt$$

Where $\dot x = \frac {dx}{dt}, \dot y = \frac {dy}{dt}$, which can be calculated from the formulas above. For the integrals, you'll want to do numerical integration rather than trying to simplify them directly. I've modified the moment integrals to be around the centroid, rather than the origin as in the Wolfram link.

Comment: Thanks so much, the integration makes much more sense now. Is there any reason why you have neglected to divide through by the area for $\overline y$ and $\overline x$ ?

Comment: I just forgot to do so. It was late at night when I typed this up, and I was rushing to finish. More importantly, I've mistaken $y_i, y_u$ as the limits of $y$ for each $x$, but the "$x$" in their formulas is different. I'll have to re-write that tonight. I don't have time right now.

Comment: No problem I assumed a typo had been made, I'm able to check some of my numerical values with a CAD program.

Comment: I've fixed the post to apply to the parametrization given here.